# How to use git to manage one repository with many different (almost unrelated) sub-packages?

Tags: git

At work we have (at least) one large repository that contains many distinct sub-packages.  These sub-packages are all of a similar theme, but almost all of them are independent of each other.

What are best practices to use git to manage this.

Is it possible to:

- Create a new tag that is made up of different directories having different tags?
- Checking out only sub-directories easily?
- In a git repo, update only a subdirectory to a given tag?

  - (One would have a single deployment checkout and we would just update certain directories to a new tag while leaving the other directories alone.)
- Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe what you want it possible.  Even if it was I believe you'd run into series issues down the road.

Instead you should use git in the way it was designed to be used.  Take a look at ASP.NET on github for instance (https://github.com/aspnet).

Sure they could've made a super complex github repo for all of asp.net, but instead they made repositories specific to each code base, which is how it should be, and compared all those repositories underneath the ASP.NET github account.  I recommend following this pattern to avoid trouble down the road.

Comment: I don't disagree with your critizism in general, but there's a lot of momentum from others to keep things as they were in different CVSs.  In SVN for example. the pattern of one big repository is very common. And lots of us end up using repositories designed by others.